# Xamarin.Forms - Reference UWP Class Lib Project type with 3rd party dll lib from UWP head project

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I have my Xamarin.Forms solution with 3 head projects for Android, iOS and UWP.

I also have a Windows Universal Class Library project **MyUWPClassLib** which contains a 3rd party .NET library in its Dependencies section like.  This is not a Nuget but just a 3rd party library we get to use from a vendor):

```
|-- MySolution.sln
  |-+ MyDroid
  |-+ MyiOS
  |-+ MyUWP
    |-ClassA (cannot reference to 3rdPartyNETLib)
  |-- MyUWPClassLib
    |-- Dependecies
      |-+ 3rdPartyNETLib
```

I have 2 questions:

1. Above 3rdPartyNETLib was added by right-click on Dependencies
   section of the MyUWPClassLibt > Add Reference > Browse > browse to the library on hard drive and select it to add it.  But this just copies the file path leaving my local drive Windows file path in the .csproj.  Obviously, this is problem because that is not the path others will have, especially not on MacOS.  How do I go around this problem?  I dont see anything like "embedded resource" or anything like that?
2. I would like to reference my 3rdPartyNETLib from MyUWP project but I am not able to figure out how to do it.  I can reference it from MyUWPClassLib but not from MyUWP head project.  I tried adding reference to MyUWPClassLib  in MyUWP but that still is not letting me reference the library inside MyUWPClassLib.  How do I do this?

Reading MS documentation on this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-add-or-remove-references-by-using-the-reference-manager?view=vs-2019 wasnt very helpful either

Comment: Have you added your 3rd library to your solution? If so, you could find it in the references manager's Projects or Shared Projects tab.

Comment: @LandLu-MSFT I explainded that under 1 above if that is what you mean.  Would you mind elaborating a bit, I provided all info what I did and how I did but I am not sure I am doing it right.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve #1, I think the only way is to add a new folder like 'Libs' folder to project, then copy 3rd parth library (note this is not a Nuget package) into this new folder.  Then in VS, right click on Libs folder > Add > Existing Item and navigate to the 3rd party library.  This will show the library in your project structure.

To solve #2, I was not able to, we just moved classes to the MyUWPClassLib and then were able to reference the 3rdPartyNETLib from these classes there.

So, the project now looks like:

```
|-- MySolution.sln
  |-+ MyDroid
  |-+ MyiOS
  |-+ MyUWP
  |-- MyUWPClassLib
    |-+ Dependecies
    |-- Libs
      |-+ 3rdPartyNETLib
    |--ClassA (now can reference 3rdPartyNETLib)
```